# Why is the selectedIndex in jList bigger than the collection size?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm busy on a GUI application in Java in which I sometimes encounter IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions when a value is added to a jList.

The exception seems to occur when a value is selected, and then another is added. I have a listener for selection changes because something needs to happen when the user selects an index, but this event is fired when a new value is added as well. I use a custom `ListModel` that just extends `AbstractListModel` and overrides the necessary methods in a perfectly valid way.

1. Why does the selection change in the program when a value is added to the list? This is not visually represented.
2. Why does the jList allow selection of an index that is not really there?

I have used jList twice now (we've recently started doing GUI in school) and I've had the problem both times. First time I solved it by clearing selection before a value is added, but that's not a really good solution. I don't think this should be necessary.

I don't know why this occurs, I have no strange code or anything. In pseudo-code, this is what happens:

```
listmodel.addValue(object);
listmodel.fireIntervalAdded();
//selection event occurs
selectedObject = listmodel.getValueAt(list.getSelectedIndex()); //indexoutofboundsexception
//index = 5, size = 3 (for example) when there are 2 objects in list and first is selected.
```

I'm not providing more code right now because I think it's not really relevant. I think anyone that understands perfectly how a jList, its listmodel and its selectionmodel work, will understand what's wrong. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I'd look at your `ListModel`. Somehow the `JList` is out of sync with your `ListModel`. Perhaps you could post your `ListModel` source.

Comment: the listmodel is extremely simple. It has an arraylist to store items (maybe this is not the right collection?), and it has only 5 methods: add object, remove object, remove index, get object at and get index of object. Four of these methods just call the appropriate method on the arraylist. When an item is removed, I do `fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, list.size());`, when an item is added I do `fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, list.size());` and then I sort the arrayList. Come to think of it, the sorting could be the cause of the trouble...

Comment: beware: _do not_ call any of the fireXX methods from code outside of the model - notifying its listeners is **the** basic responsibility of the model itself, it _must_ be implemented in the addValue method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're calling `fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, list.size())` when a **single** item is added to your list model. The [signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireIntervalAdded%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) is:

```
protected void fireIntervalAdded(Object source, int index0, int index1)
```

Note that `index0` is the starting index of the added item and `index1` is the ending index. Thus for a single item `index0` should be the same as `index1`. When you call `fireIntervalAdded` with `0, list.size()`, you are telling the JList that N items have been added, where N=`list.size()`. Thus the `JList` thinks there are more items than are in your list model.

The same goes for when you remove an item.

Comment: I never really understood that method. The javadoc says index1 doesn't even need to be greater than index0. I have fixed my problem now by adding a check in the event handler for selection changes, to see if the selected index is greater than the size - 1. I'll notify you whether you identified the real problem or not.

Comment: That dit it, thank you. I really blame my teacher for this, she said it was all right to fire these events for the entire list since it didn't really care how much actually changed. Bullshit apparantly. Thanks very much!!